# ArithmeticExcpetion in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

Hi All I am getting an ArithmeticException in my Google Play crash Reports.  I am not able to reproduce it locally  hence I have to rely on only these reports.

I am using the GridViews in my app, I am setting the Number of Columns manually instead of setting it to "auto_fit". I am not sure why this crash is happening.

The Following is the stack Trace, any help would be appreciated;

*

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
at android.widget.GridView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(GridView.java:2296)
at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:5493)
at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:5480)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:811)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:834)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:720)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:147)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$300(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:49)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:971)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

*

Thanks and Regards,
Shashi Kiran G M

Comment: It clearly states `divide by zero`

Comment: It does say Divide by Zero, But I do set the Number of Columns of the GridView. There should not be a Divide by Zero , but it is happening , Hence I am perplexed.